# How do I use concepts to constrain the argument types for variadic functions?

Tags: c++, c++20, variadic-templates, variadic-functions, c++-concepts

I have a variadic function that can take any combination of input arguments, as long as each one of those arguments is convertible to `bool`:

```cpp
#include <concepts>
#include <cstddef>

// internal helper functions
namespace {
    template <typename T>
    constexpr std::size_t count_truths(T t) {
        return (bool)t;
    }

    template <typename T, typename... Args>
    constexpr std::size_t count_truths(T t, Args... args) { // recursive variadic function
        return count_truths(t) + count_truths(args...);
    }
}

template <typename T>
concept Booly = std::convertible_to<T, bool>;

// variadic function for which all arguments should be constrained to Booly<T>
// e.g. only_one(true, false, true, false, true) = false; only_one(true, false) = true
template <typename T, typename... Args> requires Booly<T>
constexpr bool only_one(T t, Args... args) {
    return count_truths(t, args...) == 1;
}
```

I have attempted to constrain the templates using concepts to only allow bool-convertible types to be passed, but I have only managed to do so for the first parameter:

```cpp
// following lines compile:
only_one(true, false, false);
only_one(BoolConvertible(), true, false); 

// this line is correctly forced to failure due to the concept not being satisfied:
only_one(NonBoolConvertible(), false, true);

// BUT this line is not detected as a concept constraint failure (but still compilation failure):
only_one(true, NonBoolConvertible(), false, true);
```

How can I use C++20 concepts to constrain the remaining template parameters to ensure each one of them in `Args...` satisfies `Booly<>` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use C++17 fold expression to do this

```
#include <concepts>

template<std::convertible_to<bool>... Args>
constexpr bool only_one(Args... args) {
  return (bool(args) + ... + false) == 1;
}

static_assert(only_one(true, false, true, false, true) == false);
static_assert(only_one(true, false) == true);
static_assert(only_one() == false); // allow empty pack
```

Comment: What is the use of supporting an empty pack? Is it for the case where some other variadic template passes parameters to `only_one()` and it happens to be an empty set?

Comment: This makes the function more generic. You can explicitly declare the first template parameter so that the function can only accept arguments greater than 0, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 4):

You can expand `Args` via `(Booly<Args> && ...)` to pass each indivual type onto `Booly`. Chaining the result with `&&` will therefore only yield `true` if all types satisfy `Booly`.

```
template <typename T, typename... Args> requires Booly<T> && (Booly<Args> && ...)
constexpr bool only_one(T t, Args... args) {
    return count_truths(t, args...) == 1;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/35ra1Mr61):

```
struct foo {
    operator bool();
};
struct bar {};

int main() {
    only_one(true, true, false);
    only_one(foo{}, true);
    only_one(bar{}, true); //C2672 
    only_one(true, bar{}); //C2672 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After following up on a related question after drafting my own, I was inspired by the following answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/64694337/6177253) to discover an easy solution.

Rather than using `requires` to constrain on our `Booly` concept, just use the concept directly when constraining the template parameters:

```cpp
template <Booly T, Booly... Args>
constexpr bool only_one(T t, Args... args) {
    return count_truths(t, args...) == 1;
}
```

This modification now enforces the constraint on all parameters, at least as far as my own tests can tell.

I leave my question open and this answer here, in case anyone discovers any issues with my approach or potential improvements.